# If $n>0$ and $a_n\to3$, show $\sqrt{a_n}\to\sqrt{3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $n>0$ and $a_n\to3$, show $\sqrt{a_n}\to\sqrt{3}$. Hint: Show first by algebra that $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|<|a_n-3|$. Please Help.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the hint? Do you understand how to utilize the hint once you have proven it?

Comment: We are thinking that because $a_n>\sqrt{a_n}$ and $3>\sqrt{3}$ then $|a_n-3|>|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|$. That because $|a_n-3|<\epsilon$, then $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|<\epsilon$ also. Is this correct?

Comment: The last part has the right idea: $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|<|a_n-3|<\varepsilon$ implies $\sqrt{a_n}\to\sqrt{3}$. To prove the hint, note that $\sqrt{a_n}>0$ and $\sqrt{3}>1$, thus $\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{3}>1$. Now you can say $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|\cdot1<|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|\cdot|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{3}|$. Can you finish it?

Comment: The statement of the problem is weird.  "If $n>0$"?  Presumably $a_n\to 3$ means that $3$ is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$.  I guess stating that $n>0$ is a way of implying that $(a_n)_n$ is only indexed by positive integers (but it wouldn't matter if $n>89$ or $n>-2000$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$a_n-3=(\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt 3)(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt 3)\Longrightarrow$$

$$\left|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt 3\right|=\frac{|a_n-3|}{|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt3|}$$

Can you see now the inequality (for example, how the denominator on the right side *can* be way larger than the numerator?)

Answer (score 1):

Assume the hint for now: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then for some $N\in\Bbb N$, we have for $n>N$ that $$|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|<|a_n-3|<\varepsilon$$ thus we have, since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $\sqrt{a_n}\to\sqrt{3}$ as $n\to\infty$.

To prove the hint, note that $\sqrt{a_n}>0$ and $\sqrt{3}>1$, thus $\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{3}>1$. Now you can say $|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|\cdot1<|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{3}|\cdot|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{3}|=|a_n-3|$, so we're done.